# Get other variable using session

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I have table *user* like:

```
  user
=======
username
password
var
```

After login, I want to print variable `var` using username session like this, but have not had any success yet.

```
<?php

if(empty($_SESSION)){
    header("Location: logout.php");
}
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("vhts", $link);

$var = mysql_query("SELECT var FROM user where username='$username'", $link);
echo $var;

?>
```

How can this be corrected?

Comment: You have mention of a table, but show no code relating to MySQL, please post additional code, and explain exactly what the issue is that you are facing. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: Just use a `SELECT` query on your page: `SELECT var FROM user WHERE username = $username;`

Comment: @MattClark i have update the code. thanks

Comment: @SatishSaini i tried the code but not success

Comment: Where did you fetch the data? Add: `$row=mysql_fetch_array($var); echo $row['var']; ` before `echo $var;`. This should help you. ALSO, try using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) OR [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of Mysql functions because mysql functions are deprecated now.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) returns a boolean or a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). When the return value is a resource, the values can be fetched with a call to a function like [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc).

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT var FROM user where username='$username'", $link);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$var = $row['var'];   
echo $var;    
?>
```

### Important Note:

> #### Warning
>
> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)
> - [PDOStatement::fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

<sup>(Source: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)</sup>

---

So you should really consider using [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), [mysqli_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT var FROM user where username='$username'"
```

should work.., and the var would probably be in

```
$var['var']
```

and don't forget to add the fetch function

```
$var = mysql_fetch_assoc($var); // highly recommended to use mysqli / PDO
```

Comment: *"just remove the single quote"* - Oh, why is that? I doubt that that variable is an integer. Edit: This comment as per original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43792347/1